# Get order increment id in observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I have created a module to save order details to a custom mysql table after checkout completion. All works fine but the order id saves in the format **"210"(order_id)** instead of **"1000000210"(increment_id)**. How can I get this format?
My observer looks like this:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0]; 
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);     
        $this->postSaverModel->create()->doSync($orderId);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code for get order increment id in observer.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: I have tried this. It does not saves my order data to my custom mysql table though the order is created

Comment: @ShujaatShaikh share your full code you have tried.

Comment: This did worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you get order object again in your execute function ? You can get order object in your observer using this below code and get increment id also :

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); // Order object
$order_incrementId = $order->getIncrementId(); //Increment Id
```

Comment: I have tried this. It does not saves my order data to my custom mysql table though the order is created

Comment: My code : https://justpaste.it/5875wmay i know why increment id not print? @Rohan Hapani